# MYSQL: mysqldump returns empty after import

Tags: mysql

I need some help, why is it that after importing an mysqldump (table) at first you can see result, but when you exit

```
 mysql -uroot -proot
```

and select again the table then check, it returns empty.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the same database that you imported into?

Comment: yes. i only have 1 database.

Comment: It's never happened to me. I've restored many tables from dump files, and they all stick around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first connect mysql by below command-

```
mysql -uroot -proot
```

Note: assuming root is password of root user.

Now connect to database in which you imported table-

```
use my_db;
```

Now check your table by-

```
show tables;
or
show tables like 'my_table'
```

If still getting error then show how you import data and show first few lines of your backup if possible.

Comment: the table is there but no data.

Comment: show first few lines approx 20 lines from your backup means .sql file.

Answer (score 0):

Or start mysql command shell using:

```
>mysql -u youruser -p yourdatabase
```

and then check up your table.

```
mysql>select * from yourtable;
```

P.S If you didn't choose any database you get appropriate error 1046:

```
 No database selected.
```

If you don't get such error message and see you table empty YOU CHOSE WRONG DATABASE.